# Creating a simple RSS from dynamic content in PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am creating a simple RSS with dynamic content in PHP and I am using following code:

## PHP Code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$root = $doc->createElement('rss');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_data->asXML());
foreach($xml->data->item as $item)
{
    $title = $doc->createElement('title');
    $title = $root->appendChild($title);
    $text = $doc->createTextNode($item->title);
    $text = $title->appendChild($text);
    $link = $doc->createElement('link');
    $link = $root->appendChild($link);
    $text = $doc->createTextNode("http://example.com/xyz/?zyx=".$item->id);
    $text = $link->appendChild($text);
}
echo 'Wrote: ' . $doc->save("/directory/jobs00.xml") . ' bytes';
```

## What result I am getting with above code:

```
<rss>
    <title>title1</title>
    <link>http://example.com/xyz/?zyx=11008</link>
    <title>title2</title>
    <link>http:/example.com/xyz/?zyx=11009</link>
</rss>
```

## What result I want:

```
<rss>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>title1</title>
            <link>http://example.com/xyz/?zyx=11008</link>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>title2</title>
            <link>http://example.com/xyz/?zyx=11009</link>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

So what i need to modify in my code in order to achieve what i want above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to adjust the way this is built up, but it is simply an extension of what you currently have...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_data->asXML());
$channel = $doc->createElement('channel');
$root->appendChild($channel);
foreach($xml->data->item as $item)
{
    $title = $doc->createElement('title');
    $text = $doc->createTextNode($item->title);
    $text = $title->appendChild($text);
    $link = $doc->createElement('link');
    $text = $doc->createTextNode("http://example.com/xyz/?zyx=".$item->id);
    $text = $link->appendChild($text);
    $item = $doc->createElement('item');
    $item->appendChild($title);
    $item->appendChild($link);
    $channel->appendChild($item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate your quick response. I just have a quick question, how to add this "<rss version='2.0'>" in my code $root = $doc->createElement('rss');. As in the xml, it is just printing <rss>

Comment: You just need to `$root = $doc->createElement('rss');
$root->setAttribute("version", "2.0");`

Comment: *btw* you can nest the create*() calls into appendChild(), appendChild() will return the appended node. A typical chain is: `$parentNode->appendChild($document->createElement('element'))->appendChild($document->createTextNode('text content'))`. This can avoid a lot of variables, but be careful with the formatting to keep it readable.

Comment: *btw* you can nest the create*() calls into appendChild(), appendChild() will return the appended node. A typical chain is: `$parentNode->appendChild($document->createElement('element'))->appendChild($document->createTextNode('text content'))`. This can avoid a lot of variables, but be careful with the formatting to keep it readable.